# Why does {1, 2} has no a type, but decltype(a) is well-formed?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

The Standard says that `braced-init-list` has no a type. So I expected that something like `auto a = {1, 2};` is ill-formed. But it's not true at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

auto a = {1, 2};

std::initializer_list<int> init_list = {1, 3, 6, 7};

decltype(a) b = init_list;

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f12e748e208416aa)**

Moreover `decltype(a)` is `std::initializer_list<int>`. To me, it contradicts the initializer list has no the type. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decltype({1, 2})` is illegal, however, the type of `a` has already been deduced. From the *closest* draft to the C++11 standard, [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf):

§7.1.6.4/6

> Once the type of a *declarator-id* has been determined according to
>   8.3, the type of the declared variable using the *declarator-id* is determined from the type of its initializer using the rules for
>   template argument deduction. Let `T` be the type that has been
>   determined for a variable identifier `d`. Obtain `P` from `T` by
>   replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented type
>   template parameter `U` or, if the initializer is a *braced-init-list*
>   (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>`. The type deduced for the
>   variable `d` is then the deduced `A` determined using the rules of
>   template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1), where `P`
>   is a function template parameter type and the initializer for `d` is
>   the corresponding argument. If the deduction fails, the declaration is
>   ill-formed. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> auto x1 = { 1, 2 };   // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
> auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: cannot deduce element type
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

In the context of your question, the *braced-init-list* is deduced to be an `std::initializer_list<int>`, and subsequently, `decltype(a)` yields the same type.

Comment: N3337 is a rather old, non-authoritative draft of the standard.

Comment: @Potatoswatter What should I use instead?

Comment: Something newer? Visit the website containing that link. Anyway, it doesn't matter if the paragraph hasn't changed… I'm just saying the link might not be the best to provide, and saying "N3337" doesn't strengthen the argument.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Maybe you want me to remove "in accordance to".

Comment: Sure. Except that the official C++11 standard came from N3290, so N3337 is actually post-C++11. Whatever, it's not really important. +1 for you. :)

Comment: @Potatoswatter There. I always knew my meta question would backfire one day.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. BTW, why is decltype({1, 2}) ill-formed?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It's just not allowed by the grammar. `decltype` requires an *expression*, and a *braced-init-list* is not an expression.

Comment: I have one more question. In the example `auto x = {1, 2}` auto is replaced with `intializer_list<U>` where `U` is deduced into `int`. But what is the type `P` in that case? That thing I didn't get.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv `auto` follows the rules of template argument deduction. I think `P` is taken from §14.8.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

From the c++ Standard (7.1.6.4 auto specifier)

> 7....If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. If the
>   deduction is for a return statement and the initializer is a
>   braced-init-list (8.5.4), the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, obtain
>   P from T by replacing the occurrences of auto with either a new
>   invented type template parameter U or, if the initializer is a
>   **braced-init-list, with std::initializer_list**. Deduce a value for U
>   using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call
>   (14.8.2.1), where P is a function template parameter type and the
>   initializer is the corresponding argument. If the deduction fails, the
>   declaration is ill-formed. Otherwise, the type deduced for the
>   variable or return type is obtained by substituting the deduced U into
>   P. [

```
Example:
auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
```